# Pip install won't install anything "No command by the name pip install"

Tags: python, pip

Randomly it seems my pip has stopped working with the following error inside a new virtualenv:

```
$ pip install requests==2.6.0
Usage: pip COMMAND [OPTIONS]
No command by the name pip install
  (maybe you meant "pip install requests==2.6.0")
```

I've tried the following:

- Creating a new virtualenv
- Reinstalling virtualenv
- Reinstalling pip
- Reinstalling python
- Checking out repo again

Which doesn't seem to change anything, has anyone else ran into this issue before?

Note that i can pip install outside a virtualenv.

Comment: Have you tried recreating the virtualenv?

Comment: @PatrickCollins yes, several times

Comment: Try: ``strace pip install requests==2.6.0`` and paste the output to a gist that we can see?

Comment: Also try running `pip` through the full, qualified path (maybe something has been aliased strangely).

Comment: @PatrickCollins which pip, returns pip path in the virtualenv:

/Users/username/.virtualenvs/envname/bin/pip

Comment: @JamesMills that command doesn't work on on osx

Comment: Try running `/Users/username/.virtualenvs/envname/bin/pip install requests`. If it works the problem is just that your virtualenv is not in your `PATH`.

Comment: I think it's ``trace`` on BSD(s) including OS X